# My cocoapods lost a lot of Framework

Tags: cocoapods

My cocoapods like this:

```
$ pod list

424 pods were found

$ pod --version

0.29.0
```

Someone else's computer like that:

```
$ pod list

4281 pods were found

$ pod --version

0.31.0
```

How do I do like that?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
[sudo] gem install cocoapods
```

Again to get the newest version of the command line tool. To setup the master repo you then run

```
pod setup
```

Comment: Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

Comment: Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir

Comment: Command failed with status (1): [/Users/albert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/...]

    Tasks: TOP => default => ext
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)

    rake failed, exit code 1

    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/albert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 /gems/xcodeproj-0.16.0 for inspection.

Comment: Results logged to /Users/albert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/1.9.1/xcodeproj-0.16.0/gem_make.out

Comment: There are other questions about this error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939568/error-error-installing-cocoapods-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension