# CocoaPods installation failed

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, terminal, cocoapods

I am using Mavericks & xcode 5.1.1 version.

I try to install new pod say `MBProgresshud`.

but when i run `pod install` command then

I got following error:

[image]

**How to solve this?**

**Thanks**

Comment: See this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939568/error-error-installing-cocoapods-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Comment: @gran33, still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
Add a pod entry for MBProgressHUD to your Podfile pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
Install the pod(s) by running pod install.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

I think this is related to Xcode behavior, sometimes cache and memory gets loaded, and on the Derived Data directory are messy files.

### Solution

You can solve this issue by following these steps:

1. Delete Cocoa Pods project from your workspace (send it to trash and empty it). If you don't see it your workspace, navigate to your projects root folder, and delete a **folder** called **Pods** and a file called **Podfile.lock**
2. After that, at **Frameworks folder** you have a library called libpods which connects the pods with each other and searches the headers. You just need to **DELETE** it.
3. Quit Xcode. After it quits, you need to clean **Derived Data** Folder, and **empty the trash**
4. Open project and make clean by holding **CMD+SHIFT+K**
5. Edit your **podfile**, add pods you want and do a `pod install`
6. If this fails again, click on Project, a menu will open, on the left side under Project choose your own project (not target). Hit Build Settings, find Build Active Architectures and set it to NO

I had too many errors dealing with pods, and this method helped me a lot. Hope it helps you too