# gem native extension error while installing cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Am trying to reinstall `cocoapods` in my MacBook air after changing my SSD, now am getting this bellow error.

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing cocoapods:     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2/ext/ffi_c
> ```
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20200308-27204-6l0a5q.rb extconf.rb mkmf.rb can't find
>   header files for ruby at
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.12.2/gem_make.out

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Open Terminal

> curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

Reopen Terminal

> rvm install ruby-2.6
>
> rvm use ruby-2.6.3
>
> rvm --default use 2.6.3

From MahmoudKhaled's comment on 
[link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9538)

Comment: note: Go on the Apple website in the Developper section, and download the CLT .dmg archive. Then install it like you would with any other app. otherwise 
Brew installation fails

Comment: This works but piping whatever comes back from <a website> into bash is a security risk. As you basically give power to execute any command in bash to the website, in this case "https://get.rvm.io", which probably isn't malicious, but be mindful of this!

Comment: Any solution for this ? I am facing same

Comment: Well you can't install ruby 2.6 and expect to use ruby 2.6.3, so those should match. However, this post got me on the right track. Once I installed ruby 2.6 I was able to upgrade/install cocoapods

Comment: Warning: The Ruby Homebrew installer is now deprecated and has been rewritten in
Bash. Please migrate to the following command:
  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

Comment: I also had this problems when using `rbenv` to install a specific Ruby version. After uninstalling `rbenv` and using `rvm` as described above, everything was working. Thank you! Will continue using `rvm` now instead of `rbenv`.

Comment: After installing rvm, restart the terminal

Answer (score 20):

For me it worked by installing a previous version of cocoapods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.8.4
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 14):

This error can be fixed by updating ruby to it's latest version version 2.3.0 is having that issue.

You can update the ruby version to latest one by following below steps.

1. Check the version of Ruby installed on your Mac

Open terminal and type:

ruby -v

2. Install the Ruby Version Manager rvm

In terminal,

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Once this command has finished running you may need to restart your terminal for rvm to be recognised.

3. Install the latest version of Ruby

   rvm install ruby-[version]

In my case this was

```
rvm install ruby-2.7.1
```

This took a while to run as it had to install a lot of dependencies and asked for my permission a couple of times.

4. Set the latest version of Ruby as the one you want to use

You should now be running the latest version of Ruby.  You can check as before with the ruby -v command as in step 1. If you’re find that you’re not, you can set this manually.  In terminal type:

```
rvm use ruby-2.7.1
```

If you want to set this latest version of Ruby as the default version, in terminal type:

```
rvm --default use 2.7.1
```

After that done you can get your below command working for upgrading cocoapods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 7):

Probably you have not selected the Command Line Tool in Xcode > Preference > Location after an update.

The `sudo gem install cocoapods` command works after the tool is selected in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal

```
xcode-select --install
```

Reopen Terminal

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

That's it!

Comment: This worked flawlessly trying to get cocoa pods running on 10.13 with Xcode 10.1 without any of the other custom ruby upgrading in other answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Error: gem native extension error while installing cocoapods

Answer: Follow below 3 Steps issue will be fixed.

Step 1: Open XCode go to below path

XCode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools (select-Xcode)

Step 2: Open Terminal- Paste the below Command

curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

Reopen Terminal -Paste the below Commands

Note: It will take 3-5 minutes

rvm install ruby-2.6

rvm use ruby-2.6.3

rvm --default use 2.6.3

Step3:

Open Terminal- Type below Command

sudo gem install cocoapods

Now gem native extension error while installing cocoapods will not come

Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I was unable to upgrade cocopods and the problem was that homebrew was failing to update.
I noticed that when trying to install a new ruby version with nvm, it was failing because it was trying to run `homebrew update`. So it seems nvm and homebrew are connected

I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/9420

basically
`brew update` (was failing)

`git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow`

`git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask fetch --unshallow`

`brew update` (successful)

`brew install cocoapods`

It didn't solve the error, but upgraded cocoapods in another way.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXNx9.png)

I used all the codes before and showed up there, when I tried to run flutter doctor for the millesimal time...

CocoaPods 1.8.4 out of date (1.10.0 is recommended)

I just changed to:  **sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.0**

and apparently installed the cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

brew cleanup -d -v
brew install  /usr/local/bin cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg --import -
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -


curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

sudo gem install cocoapods
```

For detail pls refer: [another post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939568/error-error-installing-cocoapods-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension/73375008#73375008)

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

Step 1 (install HomeBrew)

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)

Step 2 (Run these two commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH)

echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/”YOUR USER FORLDER”/.zprofile

eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

Step 3 (now you can install cocoapods)

brew install cocoapods