# Cocoapods installing error mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby

Tags: ruby, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

`sudo gem install cocoapods` throws `mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby`.

The full output:

```
Last login: Sat Mar 21 19:00:12 on ttys000
praneeths-MacBook-Air:~ praneeth$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20200321-2325-4gn5jh.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.12.2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 22):

This also happened to me and it is because you have to update your ruby version. Someone already posted an [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9602#issuecomment-599257152) on cocoapods github repository. That issue pointed me to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60620170/1651296) and this is the solution copy-pasted from that answer:

**Open Terminal**

> curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

**Close and Reopen Terminal**

> rvm install ruby-2.6
>
> rvm use ruby-2.6.5
>
> rvm --default use 2.6.5

From MahmoudKhaled's comment on 
[link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9538)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This should be accepted as answer. I spent more than four hours and tried all answers mentioned on stackoverflow but none worked until stumbled upon this answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially the right answer. In my particular case, afterwards I also had to `sudo rm -rf /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0` to delete the old Cocoapods then `sudo gem install cocoapods` to reinstall. And `rvm` didn't work until I deleted MacPorts and reinstalled it. Wish macOS had a proper package manager.

Comment: Love you man, you saved me! Trying to serve a jekyll to github pages and all the ruby versions were crashing but 2.6 jaja