# flutter doctor - CocoaPods installed but not working

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, homebrew

using zsh - use to work in bash
brew doctor - Your system is ready to brew.
flutter doctor gives this error

```
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods. For more info, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14293.
      To re-install CocoaPods, run:
        sudo gem install cocoapods
```

sudo gem install cocoapods

```
Gives this error  
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gmp4/lib/libgmp.3.5.2.dylib  
  Referenced from: /Users/puser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby  
  Reason: image not found  
zsh: abort      sudo gem install cocoapods
```

**I can't get this error above corrected - any suggestions?**

which pod

```
/Users/puser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/pod
```

which gem

```
gem () {
    \typeset result
    (
        \typeset rvmrc
        rvm_rvmrc_files=("/etc/rvmrc" "$HOME/.rvmrc") 
        if [[ -n "${rvm_prefix:-}" ]] && ! [[ "$HOME/.rvmrc" -ef "${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc" ]]
        then
            rvm_rvmrc_files+=("${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc") 
        fi
        for rvmrc in "${rvm_rvmrc_files[@]}"
        do
            [[ -s "${rvmrc}" ]] && source "${rvmrc}" || true
        done
        unset rvm_rvmrc_files
        command gem "$@"
    ) || result=$? 
    hash -r
    return ${result:-0}
}
```

which ruby

```
/Users/puser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Using the suggestion for this post, I was able to get cocoapods reinstalled  with the commands below
[gem native extension error while installing cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60585707/gem-native-extension-error-while-installing-cocoapods)

Open Terminal

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Reopen Terminal

```
rvm install ruby-2.6

rvm use ruby-2.6.5

rvm --default use 2.6.5
```

Then this installed cocoapods as expected

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Thanks. It helps me a lot.

Comment: Thanks. you save me!

I wanna give you additional information.
If you are using Flutter on m1. then you should install it like this.
`rvm install ruby-2.6 --with-out-ext=fiddle`

In my case, the installed version is 2.6.6. so maybe you change this specific version.

Comment: Cheers!! After hours this finally worked.

Comment: Thanks. The rvm website recommended to download using `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` and then I installed `rvm install ruby-2.7.2`
Make sure you do not have CocoaPods installed using Homebrew  and if so, `brew uninstall cocoapods`. Then, `rvm --default use 2.7.2` and `sudo gem install cocoapods` worked for me

Comment: Thanks a lot... it's working for me

Comment: @mathias and @Sungjun you saved my time, i have been trying for couple of days, My system has m1 chip and nothing was working for me. My system has multiple ruby versions conflicting with `Cocapods` , your solution fixed everything.

Comment: i'm also using m1 chip, but not working, is it only me or there are a lot of problems with mac-flutter development? i find it very hard to setup and make it work

Comment: Before you mindless copy/paste the instructions like we normally do to save time, first check if you have ruby installed : ```ruby --version``` and i recommend using ```rbenv``` to setup ruby if not install and then run ```gem install cocoapods``` to install.

Comment: Amazing, searched a lot of other answers and did everything they said, it didn't work. BUT THIS DID! THANKS A LOT. YOU SAVED A LOT OF MY TIME.

Answer (score 14):

Use brew and gem

1. first uninstall by gem

   sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
2. Install cocoapods by brew

   brew install cocoapods
3. link using brew

   brew link --overwrite cocoapods

Answer (score 7):

First install `brew` package manager for Mac.
https://brew.sh

If you use macOS, system Ruby is not recommended. and you should not use it. its for system specific use. you need to install another one for user.

```
brew install rbenv
```

then install the latest version of ruby. as today its 3.1.0

```
rbenv install 3.1.0 --verbose
```

then set the global version of Ruby to be used in all shells

```
rbenv global 3.1.0
```

**close the terminal and reopen it again,** to affect the changes.

and finally install cocoapods

```
gem install cocoapods
```

as you see you don't use `sudo` command. because you are not overriding system specific configurations. when you need to use `sudo` command means you are doing something that you should avoid it.

if you are using `fastlane` and still complaining about `cocoapods`, even `cocoapods` is installed properly, reinstall `fastlane` again:

```
brew uninstall fastlane
gem install fastlane
```

if you have issues with the ruby zlib extension when building 3.1.0:

1. `brew install zlib`
2. `LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include rbenv install 3.1.0`

Answer (score 2):

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm install ruby-2.6
rvm use ruby-2.6.5
rvm --default use 2.6.5
sudo gem update
sudo gem install ffi
brew install libffi
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This error took me about one week to solve :(
The problem is mentioned clearly in the flutter output like this
This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
I had a lot of versions of ruby installed on my mac So this error happened to solve this error follow these steps

1. remove or uninstall cocoapods
2. remove all versions of ruby in your mac os except the system ruby version you can do that like this.
   [https://mac.install.guide/ruby/9.html#:~:text=Uninstall%20Ruby%20on%20Mac%20with%20rbenv,command%20to%20remove%20a%20version.&text=This%20will%20remove%20any%20gems,recommendations%20of%20newer%20version%20managers](https://mac.install.guide/ruby/9.html#:%7E:text=Uninstall%20Ruby%20on%20Mac%20with%20rbenv,command%20to%20remove%20a%20version.&text=This%20will%20remove%20any%20gems,recommendations%20of%20newer%20version%20managers).
3. install ruby again using this link https://mac.install.guide/ruby/13.html
4. install cocoapods with this command :- brew install cocoapods

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of Flutter (require ruby 2.7.2) so these steps below worked for me:

1. curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
2. rvm install ruby-2.7.2
3. rvm --default use 2.7.2
4. sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: Used 2.7.2 and 2.7.8, but unfortunately still not working

Answer (score 1):

I saw many people suggesting using rvm to manage rudy. I tried it but failed. In fact, flutter just wants me to install cocoapods. Why not simply install cocoapods directly? I ended up using

```
brew install cocoapods
```

solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
rvm install 2.6.5
sudo gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

### I am using MacBook Pro (2020) with M1 and following steps worked

---

```
url -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

rvm install ruby-2.6

rvm reinstall ruby-2.6.6 

rvm use ruby-2.6.6

rvm --default use 2.6.6

sudo gem install cocoapods
```

---

### Finally you can run flutter doctor to confirm.

```
flutter doctor
```

---

Output will be like this...

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm, locale
    en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    32.0.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Answer (score 0):

Please install latest version of ruby to solve this issue.
Use this command

```
rvm install ruby

rvm use ruby

rvm --default use
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Just run this command for installing the latest version of coc

Answer (score 0):

@Aboonajmi's answer was really helpful but I would like to add something that may be more user-oriented in the case of Apple Chip M1/M2, for every command if you encounter fail result, add the "arch -arm64" for the command to run properly, for example:

```bash
arch -arm64 brew install rbenv
```

or

```bash
sudo arch -arm64 gem install cocoapods
```

Notice to use `sudo` when installing with gem.

Hope my information can be helpful.