# I cannot install Cocapods in my MacBook Pro

Tags: xcode, shell, terminal, sdk, cocoapods

When I try to install cocoa pods, I see this error. I'm using macOS Catalina version 10.15.7. I get this error when I use "sudo gem install cocoapods"

[image]

Comment: duplicated in this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60585707/gem-native-extension-error-while-installing-cocoapods

Comment: That Definitely Helped! Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. My issue has been resolved.
Error: gem native extension error while installing cocoapods

Answer: Follow below 3 Steps issue will be fixed.

Step 1: Open XCode go to below path

XCode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools (select-Xcode)

Step 2: Open Terminal- Paste the below Command

curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

Reopen Terminal -Paste the below Commands

Note: It will take 3-5 minutes

rvm install ruby-2.6

rvm use ruby-2.6.3

rvm --default use 2.6.3

Step3:

Open Terminal- Type below Command

sudo gem install cocoapods

Now gem native extension error while installing cocoapods will not come

Issue resolved.