# Error while creating documentation with cocoa pods using Jazzy Documentation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, jazzy

I have created a new project [before pod installed]. I am trying to create documentation using **jazzy** it's creating fine.

The commend which I used in terminal

```
jazzy --min-acl internal
```

Then I installed pod file and trying to use same commend in terminal that time I am getting error like

```
2021-01-08 12:48:55.363 xcodebuild[1441:132556] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID B89EAABF-783E-4EBF-80D4-A9EAC69F77F2 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/UncrustifyPlugin.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2021-01-08 12:48:55.364 xcodebuild[1441:132556] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID B89EAABF-783E-4EBF-80D4-A9EAC69F77F2 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Crayons.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
Running xcodebuild
Could not successfully run `xcodebuild`.
Please check the build arguments.
Saved `xcodebuild` log file: /var/folders/5t/vxhnv5ys0fb217mwggmpsk6r0000gr/T/xcodebuild-1ECA7C52-5668-4982-A6FD-9D9CDCBAEDBC.log
Failed to generate documentation
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.6/lib/jazzy/executable.rb:36:in `execute_command': /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.6/bin/sourcekitten ["doc", "--"] (RuntimeError)

2021-01-08 12:48:55.363 xcodebuild[1441:132556] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID B89EAABF-783E-4EBF-80D4-A9EAC69F77F2 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/UncrustifyPlugin.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs

2021-01-08 12:48:55.364 xcodebuild[1441:132556] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID B89EAABF-783E-4EBF-80D4-A9EAC69F77F2 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Crayons.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs

Running xcodebuild

Could not successfully run `xcodebuild`.

Please check the build arguments.

Saved `xcodebuild` log file: /var/folders/5t/vxhnv5ys0fb217mwggmpsk6r0000gr/T/xcodebuild-1ECA7C52-5668-4982-A6FD-9D9CDCBAEDBC.log

Failed to generate documentation
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.6/lib/jazzy/sourcekitten.rb:266:in `run_sourcekitten'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.6/lib/jazzy/doc_builder.rb:81:in `block in build'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.6/lib/jazzy/doc_builder.rb:79:in `chdir'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.6/lib/jazzy/doc_builder.rb:79:in `build'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.6/bin/jazzy:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jazzy:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jazzy:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: i am also facing same issue ..

Comment: I'm not sure, Try installing command line tools. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20939721/5175709)

Answer (score 1):

jazzy will automatically use `Project.xcodeproj` instead of using the newly created `Project.xcworkspace` to build project. This will result in xcodebuild failed at build phase `[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock`.

You can use this command to check the build log:

```
cat /var/folders/5t/vxhnv5ys0fb217mwggmpsk6r0000gr/T/xcodebuild-1ECA7C52-5668-4982-A6FD-9D9CDCBAEDBC.log
```

The xcodebuild command which `jazzy` used to build project is

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
```

which will select `Project.xcodeproj` instead of the workspace file

You should use something like this to pass the workspace and scheme to xcodebuild

```sh
jazzy --min-acl internal -x -workspace,StackExample.xcworkspace,-scheme,StackExample
```

Reference:
[Issue 111](https://github.com/realm/jazzy/issues/111)

Comment: I tried with the following commend as you mentioned [jazzy --min-acl internal -x -workspace,DocumentorSample.xcworkspace,-scheme,DocumentorSample]. Still I am getting same error.

Comment: @KAVIYAVENKAT Can I have your log file?

Comment: Please check the doc https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OB-e_h00_Md7hHRx181mg8W62qHvs1PnqJhnZJcDeSs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The log said that there's an error in file `ChangePWVC.swift` when `import SKActivityIndicatorView`. Please check

Comment: Yes @Duc Nguyen in log it is showing error like this. But while building project app is working fine. Not getting this errors.