# This could take a while... ERROR: Error installing -- cocoapodas 1.9

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to update the cocopods, but i am gettting the next error when i execute the command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.9.0
```

> test@local ~ % sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.9.0 Building native
> extensions. This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing
> cocoapods:    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/ext/ffi_c
> ```
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0
> -r ./siteconf20210624-73396-bznqyb.rb extconf.rb checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
> the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
> options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
> --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
> --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
> --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
> --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
> --with-ffi_c-dir    --without-ffi_c-dir     --with-ffi_c-include
> --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include    --with-ffi_c-lib
> --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib    --enable-system-libffi
> --disable-system-libffi     --with-libffi-config
> --without-libffi-config     --with-pkg-config   --without-pkg-config
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in
> `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.   from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in` block in try_compile'    from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:534:in
> `with_werror'     from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in` try_compile'     from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1109:in
> `block in have_header'    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in` block in checking_for'   from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in
> `block (2 levels) in postpone'    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in` open'    from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in
> `block in postpone'   from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in` open'    from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in
> `postpone'    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in` checking_for'    from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1108:in
> `have_header'     from extconf.rb:10:in` system_libffi_usable?'   from
> extconf.rb:42:in `'
>
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
> which can be found here:
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.3/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3 for inspection. Results
> logged to
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.3/gem_make.out
> test@local ~ %

But if i try to install 1.7.5 cocoapods, it is ok.

```
test@local ~ % sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.7.5
Fetching cocoapods-1.7.5.gem
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.7.5
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.7.5
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-1.7.5
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 11 seconds
1 gem installed
test@local ~ %
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: Error installing cocoapods: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939568/error-error-installing-cocoapods-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Comment: @pkamb it was not useful for me. i tryed to do the same steps but  the mistake continues

Answer (score 9):

I fixed the mistake, you could do the next

```
brew install cocoapods
```

After

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

It permits to install the last cocoapods version

[Cocoapods](https://blog.cocoapods.org/)

Comment: what is the message ?

Comment: it says CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is
        different from the one being used to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.

Comment: do you have the  brew installed?

Comment: Yes i brew installed then brew link overwrite ... but in flutter doctor it throws above message and can't run in simulator.

Comment: Currently running the first command auto links for you, so you may not need the second one.

Answer (score 2):

please use this command . it will work

```bash
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4
```

Answer (score -1):

Install CocoaPods with Homebrew and link it:

```bash
brew install cocopods  
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
where pod
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the first posted answer.