# I have an issues with running in IOS react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have install with brew install sudogem but still have an error like this[image]

and if i go to the folder IOS and run pod install, its come an error like this[image]

I search the problem and usually the answer is sudo gem install cocoapods. but the error show like this and i have to unistall home brew cocoapods[image]

Please someone help me for my project to run in IOS, Thank you!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939568/error-error-installing-cocoapods-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Comment: No i have install with brew but still have the error

Comment: The error is podfile unable to locate node