# Error after adding shared_preferences to the flutter project

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sharedpreferences

Since I add the shared_preferences package to the project, I get the following error when running it!

```
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: I tried but I got an error!
‍‍`ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

Comment: Please try this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939568/error-error-installing-cocoapods-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939568/error-error-installing-cocoapods-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension) if you have homebrew installed