# React Expo "The plist file at path doesn't exist" error for specific Pod?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a clean React Expo project, when [trying to install a particular npm module](https://docs.sentiance.com/a-complete-integration/react-native-quick-start/include-sdk) I receive an error when building the ios app.

Here are the steps I take:

- Create new expo project with `npx create-expo-app --template bare-minimum`
- Install the npm package I need `npm install @sentiance-react-native/core`
- Build iOS app `npx expo run:ios`

On this third step when it gets to building the pod's it fails at the `SENTSDK` pod with the following error:

> The plist file at path
> `/Users/username/Documents/Projects/sentiance-rn-expo/ios/Pods/SENTSDK/SENTSDK.xcframework/Info.plist`
> doesn't exist.

I can verify no plist exists at this path but I'm unsure if I'm supposed to create one or if the Pod is just incompatible with expo.

Comment: We are seeing this issue building the intercom_flutter package for Flutter, could be a general issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: Error installing cocoapods: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939568/error-error-installing-cocoapods-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)